# multiple point time series

Tags: r, time-series

i am trying to plot multiple y values as points for a single x value (date). each timepoint has a variable number of y values. it isn't the same as plotting multiple lines on the same graph, because the relationship between points at time t and points at time t+1 is unknown. also i do not want a boxplot. i want to clearly see each point. when i try plotting this, R wants to reorganize the x axis, throwing my time series out of whack. can anyone help?

ian

```
windows()
plot(mu ~ date, xlab="Date", ylab="Mean Length (um)")
axis(1, date, format(date, "%b %d"))


site    date    mu
eldo pipe   9/3/2012    89.1365072
eldo pipe   9/3/2012    125.235052
eldo pipe   9/3/2012    135.153096
eldo pipe   9/3/2012    113.847438
eldo pipe   9/3/2012    89.732397
eldo pipe   9/3/2012    111.071991
eldo pipe   9/3/2012    122.437213
eldo pipe   9/3/2012    134.821803
eldo pipe   9/3/2012    110.687526
eldo pipe   9/3/2012    100.9783758
eldo pipe   9/3/2012    131.321202
eldo pipe   9/3/2012    123.56519    
eldo pipe   9/3/2012    136.517857
eldo pipe   9/26/2012   96.0162055
eldo pipe   9/26/2012   102.1533248
eldo pipe   9/26/2012   119.846013
eldo pipe   9/26/2012   130.1969079
eldo pipe   9/26/2012   135.3865
eldo pipe   9/26/2012   140.3697581
eldo pipe   9/26/2012   108.4733771
eldo pipe   9/26/2012   122.834203
eldo pipe   9/26/2012   137.80903
eldo pipe   9/26/2012   120.292561
eldo pipe   9/26/2012   133.746842
eldo pipe   11/2/2012   106.26084
eldo pipe   11/2/2012   125.249647
eldo pipe   11/2/2012   129.028305
eldo pipe   11/2/2012   137.932549
eldo pipe   11/2/2012   147.8790966
eldo pipe   11/2/2012   116.63048
eldo pipe   11/2/2012   121.930454
eldo pipe   11/2/2012   86.85304
eldo pipe   11/2/2012   130.63338
eldo pipe   11/2/2012   146.3816077
eldo pipe   11/2/2012   84.58692
eldo pipe   11/2/2012   103.925925
eldo pipe   11/2/2012   111.2692061
eldo pipe   11/2/2012   120.093059
eldo pipe   11/2/2012   131.782033
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a jittered `stripchart` to see all the points for each time.

```
> par(mar = c(5, 5, 4, 2))
> stripchart(mu ~ date, data = dat, method = "jitter", pch = 1, las = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: this is great. as a follow up question, is there a way to put the dates on the x axis so that the distance between points reflects the actual temporal distance? i tried to reverse them but ended up getting strange y axes as a result.

Comment: I'm not sure.  Let me do some research on it.